# spring boot redirect to a static freemarker page

Tags: spring-boot

spring boot and freemarker project, after receiving a form and processing it, want to redirect to a static page to display some info ,e.g. `Processed successfully`.

Controller code :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/send",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendApplicationMail(@ModelAttribute("application")Application application, Model model){

        System.out.println(application);
        return "redirect:success";      
    }
```

and there is `success.ftl`  in `src/main/resources/templates`

but when I submit form, browser did not redirect to `sucess.ftl`, but have below error message:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jan 24 17:50:39 CST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

but when I remove `redirect:` , just `return "succes"`, this time it's ok.
Then I tried

```
return "redirect:success.ftl";
return "redirect:/success.ftl";
```

both have the same above error page?
So how could I let it redirect to `success.ftl` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that static resource in static resource directory like `resources/static/htmlstatic.html` if the resource is just a static resource.

Use `return "redirect:/htmlstatic.html";` or `return "htmlstatic.html";`. Don't forget to put `.html` at end of static page return.

When you simply return `success` than Spring View resolver itself resolve the logical view name and return view. You need this path to be mapped in a controller or method level annotation.

Static resources don't need to be mapped using controller. DispatcherServlet map static content automatically. Using Spring boot you don't even have to configure it.

or

You might also want to remove `redirect:` and let the Spring Boot view resolver to sort out the right view based on the logical name you returned.

In your case when it return `success` than the template needs model data, so that placeholder can be replaced by key-value pair in model.

When you use `redirect:` spring kill the previous request along with model data. So model data does not survive the redirect and you get an error.

You should use **flash attributes** to pass model data while redirect or pass some data like user name as path parameter like `return "redirect:/sucess/{username}"`than use username to retrive the data again from database.

Use of Flash Attributes is easy and much better so you don't have to make another request to database or where you store that form data.

Comment: Thanks! as you said: "When you use redirect: spring kill the previous request along with model data. So model data does not survive the redirect and you get an error.",  I do not agree, because `success.ftl` does not use any placeholder, just plain content : `<h2 class="muted">Send mail successfully.</h2>`, so I think it's other reason, e.g. maybe spring only support redirecting to static page(that is in static folder) or some url configured by @RequestMapping

Comment: If its static page and requires no processing than return `return "htmlstatic.html";` from the controller method that handel your POST form and put `htmlstatic.html` in `resources/static/` directory.

You can use `return "redirect:/htmlstatic.html";` also.

But model data always gets flushed when you redirect. In this case you don't need model data. You can try yourself redirecting to a template and try to access model data from template it will cause error unless you pass that data by some other means.